# Change item checked in Navigation view

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, menuitem

[Navigation view example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ctu9F.png)

In reference to the above example of NavigationView, say I have "Go to Second item" **button** in First item layout. If I click on "Go to Second item" button, I am successfully able to go to the Second item layout, but the checked item in NavigationView remains in First item. How do I change the checked state of a MenuItem from another class which extends Fragment. If I directly click on Second item from the Menu, then the checked state changes accordingly, but how to change checked state from another class which extends Fragment.

NavigationView tutorial: [Tutorial](http://www.android4devs.com/2015/06/navigation-view-material-design-support.html) and Android documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your menu items with the tag `group` with attribute `android:checkableBehavior="single"`

Answer (score 0):

Call [`NavigationView.setCheckedItem()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html#setCheckedItem%28int%29) when you click the button.